# Skyrim Sickness Comment

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

People I walk by in the game are always mentioning that I look "sick." Is that something they just say or is that a problem? If it's a problem, how can I fix it

Comment: Are you a vampire?

Comment: No. I just started yesterday but I'm level 10

Comment: i think you just got bitten by a vampire. and you're turning into 1.

Comment: Why do you have the Dragonborn tag?

Answer (score 4):

It means that you have one or multiple diseases.

I would try the following first to cure the disease:

```
Most diseases can be cured at a shrine to a Deity. 
These shrines can be located in Hold Capitals, in Caves, or randomly in the landscape. 
For example, in Whiterun, Shrines are located in the Temple of Kynareth,
 the Hall of the Dead or the Statue of Talos (these locations are all in the Wind District).
```

For more information see the elder scrolls wiki page about [Diseases](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Diseases_(Skyrim)).

It can also mean that you have had inadequate rest and should get some sleep.